# How to split field values with Hapi.js using Joi

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I have a use case where I have an API, that gets property length in **12m** or **8ft**.

```
var schema = Joi.object({
  length: Joi.string().required(),
});
```

I need a way for [**Joi**](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to split this and return an object that structure resembles:

```
{ length: 12, type : 'm'} OR { length 8, type : 'ft'}
```

Comment: I think you have two options here: (1) Require the user to submit both the measurement (ex: 12) and the unit (ex: meters) or (2) Use a regular expression to grab the parts later: /([0-9]+)\s?([a-zA-Z]+)/g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joi is not going to do that for you. At best it can convert strings to numbers.

One option would be to add a `pre` handler method and create the morphed payload there and pass it along to the route handler. The `pre` method will only run after all of the validations have passed.

It could look something like this:

```
var createData = function (request, reply) {
   var result = /(\d+)(.+)/.exec(request.payload.length);
   var val = {
      length: result[1],
      type: result[2]
   };
   reply(val);
};

server.route({
   method: 'POST',
   path: '/',
   config: {
      validate: {
         payload: {
            length: Joi.string().required().valid('12m', '8f')
         }
      },
      pre: [{ method: createData, assign: 'morph' }],
      handler: function (request, reply) { reply(request.pre.morph); }
   }
});
```

You could also just make the user post that data object instead of just a string. That would make this whole thing much easier.